# Съезжает рамка меню

Tags: html, css

Добрый вечер, подскажите пожалуйста, что не так в коде, если на выходе получается вот такая вещь: [image]
(Хочу сделать только верхнюю и нижнюю границы у меню, но обе почему-то оказываются над ним.)

```
.menu { border-top:3px solid red; border-bottom:3px solid red; }
.menu ul {list-style:none; text-align:center;}
.menu li {float:left; padding:10px;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не хватает `clearfix`. Простейший вариант - добавить `overflow: hidden` на `ul`.

```css
.menu { border-top:3px solid red; border-bottom:3px solid red; }
.menu ul {list-style:none; text-align:center; overflow:hidden;}
.menu li {float:left; padding:10px;}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример:

```css
.menu { border-top:3px solid red; 
border-bottom:3px solid red; width:100%;display:inline-block; }

.menu ul {list-style:none; text-align:center;}
.menu li {float:left; padding:10px;}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li>Menu 1</li>
<li>Menu 2</li>
<li>Menu 3</li>
<li>Menu 4</li>
</ul>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Текст ответа противоречит коду.

Comment: спс за оперативный минус!  а что в тексте ? что противоречит ? border установлен же для класса .menu и так как нет 'высоты' для блока, то бордеры выходят над ним,

Comment: Минус был не мой. Противоречие в том, что _"блочный показ"_ - это не _`display:inline-block;`_. Однако, код в ответе верный - держи плюс, будет нолик.

Comment: 1. Всё-таки текст поправь. 2. Код можно внести в сам ответ в виде сниппета.